# FME workspace slashes ('/') missing in resulting attribute values

Tags: fme-form

I have a MS Access DB table with attributes containing slashes `/`:

[image]

When I process it with an FME workspace like (MSACCESS_JDBC reader)

[image]

the slashes disappear in the resulting attributes (FME data inspector):

[image]

Why is that so? How to preserve my slashes?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely shouldn't be happening.  We'd need to see the data to understand what is going on. My wild guess is that those column in question are "date" columns of some sort and that the raw data in fact doesn't have / in them but Access displays it like that.  If you're able, please send the data into support@safe.com (or post here) and we'll look further.